# Allow chat bookmarks with non-ASCII titles

Tags: feature-request, bug, chat, unicode, internationalization

I tried to bookmark a conversation today so I could link to it in a comment.  I had to give it a name, so I did, but the system rejected it with the bogus message "A conversation must have a title".

It did have a title, but apparently the system doesn't count Japanese characters:

[image: No bookmark for you!]

I worked around the problem by replacing "と" with the English "and".  To my surprise, the conversation ended up named "and-", at least according to the URL:

> https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/511/conversation/and-

Stripping out non-ASCII characters probably isn't the right thing to do.